# Trying to implement bootstrap 3.2 input validation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm simply trying to display an error message for an input field that is required.

After trying to search on the web, I can't seem to find a clear cut case on how to use it.

**The asterisk appears to signify it's a required field, but after clicking on the submit button, no error message appears.**

I'm using HTML5 with Twitter Bootstrap 3.2

**How can I accomplish this?**

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class='form-group'>
                                                            <span class="label label-default col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">Enter the reason and comments to stop the Shipping Request</span>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="txtStatusComments">Status Comments:</label>
                                                            <div class="required col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
                                                                <textarea id="txtSPStatusComments" rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control height-auto" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must supply comments if Accepting!"></textarea>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="hide-text">
                                                                <input type="hidden" id="txtStopGridID" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle someone has put together [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davimoreira/b9yoakyx/)

Comment: What have *you* done specifically to try and enable vaildation?

Comment: You can see the properties I have for the textarea field...

Comment: I just put a bootbox alert inside the JS if any errors occur pointing out which ones to fix.

Comment: Look up BootstrapValidator.js